# How to fix this qouting must be integer in reading csv files in python

Tags: python

```
def read_csv_fieldnames(filename, separator, quote):
    """
    Inputs:
      filename  - name of CSV file
      separator - character that separates fields
      quote     - character used to optionally quote fields
    Ouput:
      A list of strings corresponding to the field names in
      the given CSV file.
    """

    with open(filename, newline="") as csv_file:
        row_fieldnames = []
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=separator, quoting=quote)
        for row in reader:
            row_fieldnames.append(row)

    return row_fieldnames[0]


test_file1 = read_csv_fieldnames("table1.csv", ',', '"')
```

This is the data inside my csv file
Table1.csv = Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4

Expected output = ['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4']

After running the code = TypeError, quoting must be an integer

Comment: please provide sample data, expected & current behaviors. Also avoid posting code-only questions (provide context)

Comment: You haven't said what needs fixing...

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to include it. i will edit my post

Comment: One wasteful aspect of this function is that it reads and parses the whole file, but only returns the first row; instead, it can return `next(iter(reader))` or `more_itertools.first(reader)`

Comment: can i parse only the 1st row as the header? and how to fix the quoting must be an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> quote     - character used to optionally quote fields

Yes, but you passed it to the parameter `quoting` here:

```
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=separator, quoting=quote)
```

Yet `quoting` [expects an integer](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting). To specify the quote *character*, use the [`quotechar` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar).